# How to send money overseas to family without falling prey to scams?

Tags: usa, germany, banking

For the first time in my life I am looking into sending money overseas.

I know that I could "easily" do it through my bank, but I have heard from many sides that the "easy" comes at a price.

I looked into it, and basically it seems that among the possible options (banks, paypal, brick-and-mortar wiring services, online wiring), unless I missed something in the fine print or some other alternative, the cheapest is doing a wire online.

My problem is then that searching on Google or DuckDuckGo returns plenty of results, all names never heard before.

How do I go about evaluating the trustworthiness of these services and avoid giving money to scammers?

Comment: *I have heard from many sides that the "easy" comes at a price.* So what. Everything has a price. Ask your bank how much it would cost. The rates may be available on their website, unless the operation you are contemplating is a bit unusual. Some money exchanges are very well-known and reputable. If you are willing to try a lesser-known provider, at least make sure it is licensed and authorized in the country of origin/operation. For example in the UK there is the FSA, other countries have similar bodies that regulate financial institutions.

Comment: No, do not ask your bank how much it costs, rather open an account in the bank where it costs less.

Comment: How much is the difference in fees likely to be? Is the time and trouble of trying to evaluate the trustworthiness of a service you’ve never heard of (and probably *still* not being 100% sure) worth it for the sake of saving a few $? You might try asking on https://money.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: I don't undertand what "opinions" I would be asking here. All I got in the comments is frame challenges (to me useless, because that's where the opinions are)

Comment: If you send money through Western Union, you can be confident that the right recipient will get it. (Although Western Union is also used by scammers - if you use them to send money to a scammer, they will make sure the scammer gets it. And there's no way to get your money back).